# How can i replace HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING in POI 4.1

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can i replace HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING in POI 4.1.

```
if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
 System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HSSFCell.getCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getCellType--) returns a [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) now.  So it needs to be compared to `CellType.STRING` now instead to `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
if (cell != null) {
 if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
  System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
 }
}
```